# How to remove user from a specified group in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Let's assume `user01` has two groups defined: `groupA` and `groupB` (in addition to the primary group).

I can add the account to `groupC` (ensure `user01` belongs to `groupC`) using:

```
- user: name=user01 groups=groupC append=yes
```

How can I remove `user01` from `groupB` (ensure `user01` does not belong to `groupB`) without specifying all the groups the account should belong to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't with just the normal user module.

However, with some fairly crazy gyrations, you can do it in a playbook.
I'm not sure I recommend this though; it was just an interesting exercise. (I did test this and it worked.)

The interesting part is the task "build the new groups list", which removes a list entry. If calling .remove() on a python list returned the new list, that would all be uneccessary.

```
---
- hosts: target
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    group_to_remove: admins
    new_groups_list: []
    user_to_check: user1

  tasks:
    - user: name="{{ user_to_check }}" groups=testers,developers,admins

    - name: get the current groups list
      command: groups "{{ user_to_check }}"
      register: current_groups

    - debug: var=current_groups

    # parse the output of the groups command into a python list
    # of the current groups
    - set_fact:
        current_group_list: "{{ current_groups.stdout.replace( user_to_check+' : ','').split(' ') }}"

    - name: show user_group_list
      debug: var=current_group_list

    - name: build the new groups list
      set_fact:
        new_groups_list: "{{ new_groups_list + [ item  ]  }}"
      no_log: False
      when: "not '{{ group_to_remove }}' == '{{ item }}'"
      with_items: "{{ current_group_list }}"

    # turn the list, into a comma-delimited string
    - set_fact:
        new_groups: "{{ ','.join(new_groups_list) }}"

    - name: show new_groups_list
      debug: var=new_groups

    - name: set new user groups
      user: name="{{ user_to_check }}" groups="{{ new_groups }}"

    - name: get the new groups list
      command: groups "{{ user_to_check }}"
      register: new_groups

    - debug: var=new_groups
```

Answer (score 6):

The provided solutions seem quite complex, given the fact that both the user and the group that shall be removed are known. I used this ansible code, which is sufficient to get an idempotent behaviour and has the same dependency to gpasswd as other suggested solutions.

```
- name: remove user dovecot from the certuser group
  become: true
  command: "gpasswd -d dovecot certuser"
  register: command_result
  changed_when: "not 'is not a member of' in command_result.stderr"
  failed_when: false
```

If you believe the task should fail if the group does not exist, just modify the last line:

```
- name: remove user dovecot from the certuser group
  become: true
  command: "gpasswd -d dovecot certuser"
  register: command_result
  changed_when: "not 'is not a member of' in command_result.stderr"
  failed_when: "'does not exist in /etc/group' in command_result.stderr"
```

Comment: May be add a failure condition if group does not exist.

`failed_when: "'does not exist in /etc/group' in command_result.stderr"`

Comment: If the group does not exist then the user is not part of that group - my definition of an idempotent functionality. But a good point as others may see it different.

Answer (score 3):

Improving a bit the [answer from higuita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452715/7653022) adding a right condition:

```
- name: Get info from user1
  user:
    name: user1
    state: present
  register: user1_data

- name: remove user1 user from grouptodelete group
  become: true
  command: "gpasswd -d user1 grouptodelete"
  when: user1_data.groups is defined and 'grouptodelete' in user1_data.groups
```

Comment: This would have been a pretty clean workaround, but `user1_data.groups` is not defined in my case, at least not in check mode.

Answer (score 1):

that feature is missing and this is the open bug for that:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11024

As workaround, use something like this.

```
  become: true
  shell: "/usr/sbin/delgroup telegraf varnish"
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: ansible_hostname | lower not in groups['varnish'] | lower
```

Please adapt this to your down needs, i'm removing telegraf user from host varnish group if the current host is not in the ansible group varnish list

Comment: Are you sure that condition does what you think it does? Checking the official docs (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) it says: "`groups` is a list of all the groups (and hosts) in the inventory". It is about the hosts groups for Ansible, not the groups existing in the host itself, as well as `ansible_hostname`, which is the host itself, not the user

Comment: That works for me. i'm testing if current host is not a varnish server, not testing users nor host groups.
i'm removing the telegraf user from the host varnish group if the current machine is not in ansible group named varnish. In other words, if a machine stops being a varnish server, telegraf should lose access to any varnish files

Comment: Yes, now I get what you mean. But if you are running molecule tests in your role, this would fail because it is not idempotent, as this task would be performed even if the user `telegraf` is not already in the `varnish` group. And this stands for your own purpose, if people is not calling the servers equally as the user, this would not work properly.

Comment: Actually, right now, in my code i have the `ignore_errors: yes` (updated above too), after some unwanted errors  made me notice the problem. The names and similar are non-issue, the basic idea is to use a command line to remove your a user from the group instead of waiting for ansible to fix their issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using Ansible too you have to use the right flag

You need to use the append flag to no or false to tell Ansbile not to append the user to group

```
- user:
    name: hive
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: hadoop
    append: no
    state: present
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as per https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/user_module.html#parameters, append: "If no, user will only be added to the groups specified in groups, removing them from all other groups."

Comment: I use this feature on daily basis on ansible 2.4 and running stuff in prod as well.

Comment: If for some reason the user is added to more groups, running this will remove it. It does not fit the case of just wanting to delete it from one group.

Answer (score 0):

Example : Remove all users from "docker" group

```
- name: get all user into docker group
  shell: |
    awk -F':' '/^docker:/ {print $4}' /etc/group
  register: users_intogroup_docker
  changed_when: False

- name: no user into docker group
  command: gpasswd -d {{ item }} docker
  with_items: "{{ users_intogroup_docker.stdout.split(',') }}"
  when: not item in [""]
```